# EF 4.1 code first: one-to-many mapping problem

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, one-to-many, entity-framework-4.1

In my domain I have these classes (in simplified form)

```
    public class Document
    {    
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public IList<MetadataValue> MetadataList { get; set; }
    }

    public class MetadataValue
    {
        public string DocumentId { get; set; }
        public string Metadata { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

A document may have many metadata. In mapping of Document entity I have:

```
    HasMany<MetadataValue>(x => x.MetadataList)
        .WithRequired()
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.DocumentId);
```

When I persist Document object its metadata list is also persisted. But when I retrieve Document object its metadata list is always null. What is wrong with this mapping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of making the navigation property `virtual` to enable lazy loading - as proposed by Paige Cook - you can also eager load the collection:

```
var query = dbContext.Documents
    .Where(d => d.Id == "MyDoc")
    .Include(d => d.MetadataList);
```

If you don't use lazy loading you always have to define explicitely in your queries which navigation property - references and collections - you want to load together with your entity.

Comment: I couldnt find Inlude method of IQueryable. In which namespace its included?

Comment: @arch stanton: Reference to `EntityFramework.dll` is necessary and `using System.Data.Entity;` as included namespace.

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare your MetadataList property on your Document class as a virtual ICollection so that EF can map it properly:

```
public virtual ICollection<MetadataValue> MetadataList { get; set; }
```

Comment: `virtual` and `ICollection` are *options*, not necessary requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use MetadataValueID as the key (instead of using DocumentID).